# Angular Directive dropdown box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning Angular JS and trying to create a dropdown box as a directive.  I have done this simply (in my actual code I use a templateURL) but now I need to be able to read the attribute 'value' from the dropdown box and respond to the changes.

I can do this in Jquery and have written a small scrip to show the behaviour that I want to see.  My question is how to replicate this behaviour just using Angular.

Here is the test script in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vguftwf8zfY7ZeAoGYfq

It is also below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <title>This is a test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dd"><runs></runs></div>
<div id="other">Here is other input box
    <input type='text' name='other'/></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js">     </script>
    <script>
        'use strict'
        var app = angular.module('test', [])
        app.directive('runs', function() {
            return{
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<select name="runs" id="runs"><option value ="0">Zero</option><option value ="1">One</option><option value ="2">Two</option><option value ="other">Other</option></select>',
                scope: {
                    value: '@'
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


                    //if (attrs('value') === 'other'){
                    //    set other div to visible
                    // }
                }
            }
        })

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#other").hide();
            $("#runs").change(function(){
                if($("#runs option:selected").val()==="other"){
                    $("#other").show();
                } else{
                    $("#other").hide();
                }

            })
        })

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you want the `<select>` to be bound to a data model using `ng-model`.

When angular encounters `ng-model` in the html, if the scope that it is encountered within doesn't contain this variable, angular creates it.

```
<select ng-model="model.runs">
```

I arbitrarily named the object `model` and the property `runs`.

Now you can use `ng-show` to evaluate that value :

```
<div id="other" ng-show="model.runs=='other'">
```

Many of angular's built in directives will evaluate javascript expressions. In this case will evaluate `model.runs=='other'` as a boolean.

Note that changing the select will now toggle the display of an element without any additional script having been written, just a little bit of markup modification

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/QPosdHyGWx8P4C79jIBR?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks I knew there was an easy way to do this but I couldn't work it out.  By the way why is there a blank line now in the drop down box?

Comment: ahh...look at `select` docs...there is a `nullable` directive can apply . The blanks are done by angular since most `select` use `ng-options` to populate

Answer (score 0):

Here is a directive example, hope this will help you.

`<kaze-dropdown is-button ng-model="item" items="options" callback="callbackFunc(item)"></kaze-dropdown>`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kazehaya/93rwhgq9/)